# usage of multiple properties in php

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to learn oop in php, but the below code is not working could someone provide an alternate answer?

```
<?php
    class abc {
        public $a = 1;
        $b = $a;

        function foo(){
            //some function..
        }

    }
?>
```

I want to assign value of variable "a" to variable "b".

Comment: You can only initialize variables to static values outside of class methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the value of `$a` to `$b` like so: `$this->b = $this->a` within the `__construct` method which gets called upon [object creation](http://ideone.com/cyEeu), assuming you're running PHP 5.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you've asked for but it might (or might not) solve your problem:
You can define a constant that is used to initialize *both* members, $a *and* $b.

```
<?php
class abc {
    const defaultValue = 1;
    public $a = self::defaultValue;
    public $b = self::defaultValue;

    function foo(){
        //some function..
    }
}

$abc = new abc;
var_dump($abc);
```

prints

```
object(abc)#1 (2) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(1)
  ["b"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: a better notation would be `self::defaultValue` as your class itself is more protected against class naming changes and its even more obvious.